# Operator splitting for 4 subproblems

Tags: numerical-modelling, operator-splitting

Typically an ODE System which involves 2 different physical problems such as diffusion and advection can be numerically approached by the well known Strang operator splitting scheme. I'm wondering if there's a generalization of this scheme to an arbitrary number of subproblems.

In my case, there's an additional issue: I got 4 subproblems, two of which have a smaller time-scale (Maxwell equations with time-varying medium) than the remaining 2 (advection/diffusion).
Any ideas, keywords, hints?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, see in Numerical Recipes "Operator Splitting Methods Generally" and follow the references there...

Answer (score 1):

In general, a problem with different parts can be split, then each part is solved separately, then the solutions for each flow are composed back to obtain the final solution.

For a description of these methods you can refer to *A concise introduction to Geometric Numerical Integration* by Blanes & Casas and to *Geometric Numerical Integration* by Hairer, Lubich, Wanner. But, as far as I remember, they do not give example of 3D problems.

As a more specific example, maybe [*A splitting approach for the magnetic Schrödinger equation*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042716304101), where kinetic-potential-advection splitting is performed, will be of use.